# delete a specific line from text in c without stdio.h

Tags: c, linux, file-io

i have a homework for my university in C and in the program i must develop there is a function that must delete a specific line from a text file. I searched before i post this and i found some answers but our teacher told us to access files only with system calls(so i can't use functions like fopen etc. Only open read etc) and not with functions and types of stdlib.h, not to use a temp file and not to use arrays to save temporarily the content of our file and then put it back in the main file.

What i want exactly to do, is to ask the user to enter a subject and a date which i'll put in 2 arrays. Then i'll search a text file to see if there is an entry for this subject and the exact date and if exists, i want to do delete this line. If this line is the last line in the text file, then i can just use the truncate function to make the file smaller but i can't find a way to implement it if the line i must delete is the first line of the text file or between.

I really would appreciate your help here.

Comment: You should make an attempt and show your code so far to obtain help on SO. Use the fact that a text line is a string of characters ending in `\n` (Unix) or `\r\n` (Windows/DOS).

Comment: Read the file into an array of lines. Delete the line or lines as required. Open the file again in write mode and write out the un-delete lines.

Comment: Right now when i read from a file i use read, to move the file descriptor i use lseek and to write to the file i use the write.
I also use open, close, dup.

Comment: Sounds like you've written some code. Why not show what you've tried so far and what your strategy is? You haven't indicated how you're supposed to identify the line you want to delete, but I don't think you need to read the whole file into memory to do this. You can open the input file, open (create) an output file, and read/write lines as you go. Just omit the one you're supposed to omit.

Comment: @zarzonis - That is a tautology

Comment: The homework is a management of the exams for a student. The student can add subject(check if the subject exists in courses.txt) then add date and then add score. After some checks i put them in student.txt Another function is to search all entries for a particular subject in student.txt and print them. Another function is to find all entries in student.txt with score >=5.0 and calculate the average score. I implemented all of these functions and work fine. The last thing that i must implement is the function to search in student.txt for a subject that the user will provide with particular

Comment: "system calls", please add tag for the system. Probably [tag:linux]? With text files there's the extra significance to this, as text file line endings are different on different OS.

Comment: date and if there is a such entry, i must delete this line. I can't find a solution to this problem with all limitations that my teacher enforced. Here is an example of the courses.txt and student.txt
https://app.box.com/s/igw0d4uwdjaju808bxvd

https://app.box.com/s/w0gfhzr877oe8u70skor

Comment: @hyde
yes it's for linux.

Comment: If you're allowed to use mmap, this is easy: map the whole file (with write access) into memory, find the start offset of your pattern in the mapped memory region, keep a pointer to this position and advance with another one until it reaches the end of the pattern; then, advance in parallel the two pointers, copying the character pointed to by the second one in the first one, and finally, truncate the file.

Comment: @doukremt I just sent an email to my teacher and he said that i'm not allowed to use mmap because i must include another header file.
i don't know why, but my question marked with a negative vote. I didn't found anything that answers my question on this site. I searched a lot.
I tried to combine all answers from all of you and i came up with a solution(which i didn't tried yet). I'll find with my searching algorithm if the exact subject and date exists in student txt and if yes, i'll keep the offset, then move the seek_cur to the location of the last entry of the subject.txt, read this entry

Comment: and then write it to the offset of the entry i found. After that, i'll truncate the file. You solution is probably better because i don't change the sequence of entries, but it's way harder to implement without mmap.

Comment: @zarzonis: It's easier with mmap because you can manipulate the file content with pointers, but you can still do this by opening the file two times at the same time (one for reading, the other for writing), and proceed as I described: read one character from one side, and write it on the other. The problem with your approach is that you can't cope with variable-length lines: what if the last entry of the file is longer than the one you intend to remove? Otherwise, it is certainly faster.

Comment: I know that it easier but unfortunately i'm not allowed to use it.
If you check the files i uploaded you will see that the have a specific format. There are 79 characters in each line in student.txt +1 \n character. For example, the subject string has 64 character max + 1 for \0. When i read a subject from the user, i fill it with spaces so it fills the whole array. So for delete what i finally did and seems to work fine, is to find the offset of the entry i want to delete then go 80 characters before seek_end, read 80 characters and  write it at the offset i found before. Then all entries

Comment: move 80 characters. So i have the last entry twice for a while. Then i truncate the file by 80 characters and i'm done.
Here is the code without any checks for the returned values of the system calls due to space limitations.

Comment: offsetOfEntryToDelete = currentOffset;
  currentOffset = lseek(StudentFD, -80*((off_t)sizeof(char)),     SEEK_END);
 
bytes_read = read(StudentFD, entryToCopy, 80*(off_t) sizeof(char));
currentOffset = lseek(StudentFD, offsetOfEntryToDelete*sizeof(char), SEEK_SET);

write(StudentFD, entryToCopy, 80*((off_t)sizeof(char)));
lseek(StudentFD, 0L, SEEK_SET);
currentOffset = lseek(StudentFD, 0, SEEK_END);
 truncate("student.txt", (currentOffset - 80)*(off_t)sizeof(char));
            close(StudentFD);

Comment: I don't know how to arrange the code here. If someone knows, please feel free to edit my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the system calls you need

- [open](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)
- [read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read)
- [write](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write)
- [close](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close)
- [lseek](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek)

Then devise an algorithm to use them

Couple of possibilities.

Read the whole file into memory. Do the business. Write it back out.

Or Read a line and write it back to the same file in the new location

Comment: Why are you linking to linux.die.net?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan don't know why he is, but I do it because Google ranks it top hit for Unix man pages. Also, it appears question is about Linux anyway.

Comment: @hyde Question is tagged C

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If you have alternative site for Posix/Linux system call documentation, I'm all ears, I'm sure there are good alternatives. But OS in question is Linux, so man pages of appropriate system calls is the right documentation to look at.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan kernel.org seems to redirect to [man7.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/) for stuff like this, but that indeed seems a better place to link for some man pages. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Good as any other web site for manual pages

Comment: Even if the question is about Linux, people should be educated to write portable code. I changed the links to point to the current POSIX man pages.

Comment: @nwellnhof - Will put back. Write your own answer. Why edit my answer just because you feel like it when it was a reasonable answer as the question **IS** about Linux

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can edit any answer if you feel like it. BTW, I only changed some links to point to POSIX man pages. Linux adheres to the POSIX standard so this should do no harm. IMO this improves the answer because it educates people about writing portable code.

Comment: @nwellnhof - I beg to differ. Anyway why not write your own answer?

Comment: If you prefer an ad-funded website with no original content over an official standard, so be it.

Comment: @nwellnhof - I prefer people not to inter in my answers. All web sites have funding. One way or the other.